# google map load issue in wordpress custom javascript code

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, google-maps

I have a JavaScript code which loads Google map. But it is not loading map properly. Check [this screenshot](http://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/78595/08a0294f7612cb4a88c188a0f1426967) for issue. Map should fit in whole window. But it load only in left corner.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is due to not calling the java script function, which is initializing the process. As per me there is a function in your java script code like initialize().

May be you are calling this function on page load, just call this function on any button click, your map will load automatically.